# How to handle when MetaMask popup triggers

Tags: metamask

My goal is fetching method ID before transaction call. Basically, I want to learn if transaction is Transfer, Approval or something else. How can I handle those when Metamask triggers on my client.

Comment: Metamask is a browser plugin so you can't detect when its dialogs are triggered. In the client side usually window.ethereum is the web3's provider, so you could hook it and detect when a send transaction is called.

Comment: @Ismael I couldn't find any hook for detect transaction calls.

Comment: Take a look at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193, in the examples session. There's no hook just hook `ethereum.request` by yourself. It'll be done client side so you don't have access to metamask internals.